# how can i extend the function with the processing times?

Tags: simulation, anylogic, modeling

I have a function for the setuptime + processingtime for my Agents that go into the Serviceblock. The first Agent that go into the service Block doesn't have a setuptime. They have only processing time. The first agent can be variable, so i would have to use an if function.

I want that the Serviceblock take only the processingtime for the first Agent and then the setuptime for the successor. But the first Agent can be variable, so i have to wirite an if function like this:

`if Agent A then return X (processingtime), else if Agent B then return X (processingtime)... and so on.`

This is the start, and then it goes into the setuptime + processingtime function. But how i can say in the function, that the first Agent have only the processingtime? Because the first Agent doesnt have a currentAgent.

My function for the setuptime + processingtime is this:

```
if (currentAgent instanceof Oberteil && predecessor instanceof Unterteil) {
    return 45;
} else if (currentAgent instanceof Oberteil && predecessor instanceof Halteteil) {
    return 40;
}else if (currentAgent instanceof Oberteil && predecessor instanceof Ring) {
    return 45;
}else if (currentAgent instanceof Unterteil && predecessor instanceof Oberteil) {
    return 45;
}else if (currentAgent instanceof Unterteil && predecessor instanceof Halteteil) {
    return 40;
}else if (currentAgent instanceof Unterteil && predecessor instanceof Ring) {
    return 45;
}else if (currentAgent instanceof Halteteil && predecessor instanceof Oberteil) {
    return 40;
}else if (currentAgent instanceof Halteteil && predecessor instanceof Unterteil) {
    return 40;
}else if (currentAgent instanceof Halteteil && predecessor instanceof Ring) {
    return 45;
}else if (currentAgent instanceof Ring && predecessor instanceof Oberteil) {
    return 45;
}else if (currentAgent instanceof Ring && predecessor instanceof Unterteil) {
    return 45;
}else if (currentAgent instanceof Ring && predecessor instanceof Halteteil) {
    return 45;
}
return 2;
```

Comment: Please clarify how you want to apply setup times and processing time and how they shall relate to the service block. Currently unclear what the problem is, what you tried and what you need to do 

Comment: I edit the Question. I hope this is now clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add this check at the start of the function:

```
if (predecessor == null) { // this is the first agent that has no predecessor
    return ...; // return only processingTime
} else {
    // continue with your existing code here
    if (currentAgent instanceof Oberteil && predecessor instanceof Unterteil) {
        return 45;
    } else if (currentAgent instanceof Oberteil && predecessor instanceof Halteteil) {
        return 40;
    ... and so on
}
```